# 404 while trying to make dockerized nginx serve static files mounted in a volume

Tags: docker, nginx, static

I'm struggling to setup nginx inside a docker container. I basically have two containers:

- a php:7-apache container that serves a dynamic website, including its static contents.
- a nginx container, with a volume mounted inside it as a **/home/www-data/static-content** folder (I do this in my docker-compose.yml), to try to serve a static website (unrelated to the one served by the apache container).

I want to use the domain **dynamic.localhost** to serve my dynamic website, and **static.localhost** to serve my static website only made up of static files.

I have the following Dockerfile for my nginx container:

```
########## BASE #########

FROM nginx:stable

########## CONFIGURATION ##########

ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

ENV user www-data

COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY ./site.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

RUN touch /var/run/nginx.pid && \
    chown -R ${user}:${user} /var/run/nginx.pid && \
    chown -R www-data:www-data /var/cache/nginx

RUN chown -R ${user} /home/${user}/ && \
    chgrp -R ${user} /home/${user}/

USER ${user}
```

As you see I'm using two configuration files for nginx: nginx.conf and site.conf.
Here is nginx.conf (it's not important because there is nothing special in it but if I'm doing something wrong just let me know):

```
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;
pid       /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    log_format main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                    '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main;
    sendfile on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

And here is the file site.conf that I have been failing miserably at writing correctly for days now:

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name static.localhost;
    root /home/www-data/static-content;

    location / {
        try_files $uri =404;
    }
}

server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name dynamic.localhost;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://dynamic;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host:8080;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 8080;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host:8080;
    }
}
```

(http://dynamic passes the request to the apache container that I name "dynamic").

So basically I keep getting 404 for whatever file I try to access in my static-content directory. E.g.:

- static.localhost:8080/index.html should serve /home/www-data/static-content/index.html but I get 404 instead.
- static.localhost:8080/css/style.css should serve /home/www-data/static-content/css/style.css but I get 404 too.

I tried various things, like writing *try_files /home/www-data/static-content/$uri*, but I didn't get any result. I read some parts of nginx documentation and searched on Stack Overflow but nothing that I found helped me. If I made a stupid mistake I apologize, but the only thing that I care about now is to get this to work, and to understand what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Well first off did you connect to your running docker image and look to see what is in the `/home/www-data/static-content`? Could be a simple volume mounting issue.

Comment: Yes I did. The volume is correctly mounted at the right place. The only problem is that its owner is different from the owner running nginx in the container (www-data). But if it were the cause of my problem I guess I would be getting 403s not 404s.

Comment: Anything in the nginx logs that point to anything useful?

Comment: The logs are not very verbose. Does my site.conf seem ok to you?

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problems by simply not using a volume for the static files but copying them in the container. I suspect it's a problem of permissions with the way the volume is mounted by docker-compose and the nginx process running as non-root.
It's not a perfect solution since I have to give up on using a volume but it'll do.

Answer (score 1):

I had a same issue and I had to change permissions to mounted volume files for user group.

On dockerfile 
`RUN useradd -G root,www-data -u 1000 ${user}`

and changed permissions on host files 
`chmod 775 /home/www-data/static-content -R`